# Why do some words in VBA automatically have a lowercase first letter?

Tags: excel, vba, variables, capitalization

Has anyone seen the phenomenon where certain words, not keywords, but just certain variable names will automatically change the first letter to lower case. It's quite annoying, for example, I have a variable I tried to name "SiteNumber" and everytime it switches across the whole module to "siteNumber", I have tried a Replace All and still nothing works. The same thing happens when I try to name a variable "CarrierName", everytime it changes automatically to "carrierName". Any insight?

Comment: Side note: Some would argue that variable naming convention would be for the first letter to be lowercase, btw.

Comment: Then somewhere you have a variable declaration that is spelled that way.

Comment: @BigBen , but another convention, preferred by me, is capitalizing the first letter of each word, I forget if it has a name, but that convention looks better in my opinion.

Comment: @ Scott Craner, I have used the find popup box to search the whole module, change the names to something else, and then try to rechange them back but everytime it still becomes lowercase.

Comment: Check your other modules for `public` delcarations and or modules themselves that have them.

Comment: If you write `Dim SiteNumber`, you're saying it changes to `siteNumber`?

Comment: @BigBen, that is correct, I originally didn't have a Dim statement because I was fleshing out the code and trying to get something to work, but I put a Dim statement, Replaced all, and that seemed to work, the IDE can be quirky sometimes. Thanks!

Comment: Best practice is to always declare your variables. Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module. Then I recommend going to *Tools* > *Options* > *Require Variable Declaration* to have it added automatically going forward.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try writing

```
Dim SiteNumber, CarrierName
```

only it should work alone and change the `Var` names in whole code but sense you said that you used replace all tool, i am not certain if its going to work or not, but it is worth to give it a try.